# R source build fails because of lack of pcre support

Tags: r, pcre

I am trying to compile R 3.3.1 under Ubuntu 14.04.  Despite attempting to install both the ubuntu pcre3 packages as well as (later) installing pcre-8.37 from source, I'm still getting the following when I run ./configure in R-3.3.1

```
checking for pcre_fullinfo in -lpcre... yes
checking pcre.h usability... yes
checking pcre.h presence... yes
checking for pcre.h... yes
checking pcre/pcre.h usability... no
checking pcre/pcre.h presence... no
checking for pcre/pcre.h... no
checking if PCRE version >= 8.10, < 10.0 and has UTF-8 support... no
checking whether PCRE support suffices... configure: error: pcre >= 8.10 library and headers are required
```

This occurs even when I rebuild pcre like so:

```
./configure --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties
make
make install
```

per the few references to this problem I've found online.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to install the '-dev' version of the *library*, `sudo apt install libpcre3-dev` ?

Comment: Yes,  I've definitely tried the dev version, and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @glossarch `libpecre3-dev` solves my problem in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem like you, and the following command saved me!

```
yum install pcre pcre-devel
```

I'am sure you have pcre installed in your system, but it seems like R need the pcre-devel version!