# When compiling R 3.4.4 in Linux, got this kind of errors: undefined reference to `pcre_jit_stack_alloc'

Tags: r

I tried compiling R 3.4.4 at a linux system (CentOS) locally (I don't have administrative right to the system). In `make`, I consistently got these errors:

grep.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `pcre_jit_stack_alloc`
grep.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `pcre_assign_jit_stack`
grep.o: In function `do_strsplit`:
grep.c:(.text+0x1f8a): undefined reference to `pcre_free_study`
grep.o: In function `do_grep`:
grep.c:(.text+0x3ca5): undefined reference to `pcre_free_study`
grep.o: In function `do_gsub`:
grep.c:(.text+0x85c6): undefined reference to `pcre_free_study`
grep.o: In function `do_regexpr`:
grep.c:(.text+0xb3e6): undefined reference to `pcre_free_study'

I encountered similar errors for R 3.4.3. I thought R 3.4.4 may not have this problem on that system but it turned out that I was wrong. I could successfully compile R 3.3.2 on the same system. I was also told that the `pcre` on the system is up to date (pcre/8.41/gcc/4.9.3).

What are the possible reasons for this kind of errors?

Comment: I use [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) for this stuff - makes life so much easier.  Installing R is then as simple as `conda install -c r r-base`.  Note that 3.4.4 was just released, so it hasn't been pushed to the anaconda package repository yet.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't have administrative right to the system. Can I use Miniconda to install packages?

Comment: That won't be a problem - everything installs into local directories. I have the same situation for cluster computing and `conda` (plus the [Bioconda repository](https://bioconda.github.io/)) is how I manage 99% of my software installations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R source build fails because of lack of pcre support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603909/r-source-build-fails-because-of-lack-of-pcre-support)

Answer (score 1):

FYI for people trying the `conda` approach. I was able to install R-3.4.3 using `conda install -c r r=3.4.3`. I noticed, however, that it installed Microsoft R Open (MRO) instead of vanilla R.

This solves my problem for now. Thanks very much for the suggestion merv. I would still want to know why building R from source produces the errors mentioned in the post though.